# Proofs of boundedness

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'd like to prove that $(-1)^n$ is bounded. Intuitively I know that it is, because the only values it assumes are -1 and 1, but it doesn't converge so I can't say that it's bounded because it converges. What else can I do?

Similarly, is it possible to prove
$$ \sqrt \frac{n}{n+2} $$ is bounded without resorting to finding its limit to show that it converges?

Comment: $x_n=(-1)^n$ is bounded because $|x_n|\le 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Sure, that's intuitively obvious, but does that actually count as a "proof"?

Comment: Yes, it does. That shows directly that it satisfies the *definition* of *bounded*.

Comment: @Why-Seven-Six: The argument by Brian M. Scott is a proof; by definition a sequence $(x_{n})$ is bounded iff there is some $M \geq 0$ such that $|x_{n}| \leq M$ for all $n \geq 1$; take $M := 1$.

Comment: For the second question, just observe that $0\le\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+2}}<1$ for all $n$.